# Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'checker_1' is violated

Tags: mysql, constraints, mysql-workbench, check-constraints

My question says that it wants me to add a constraint so that the company cannot purchase any more car that were made before 2018.The problem is that my database already has info about cars that were made before 2018. I cant delete the table because it will mess with some of my other queries . Can i get some advice on it?

My code below for vehicle table

```
create table Vehicle(
LicensePlate varchar(48) primary key,  /*Primary key for table Vehicle for License plate, variable can hold up to 48 characters*/
Make varchar (48),  
CarYear int 
);

insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('1234 AA','Toyota',1970);
insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('1237 AB','Mazda',1995);
insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('1892 BG','Toyota',2000);
insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('1876 FA','Nissan',1999);
insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('3021 AA','Mazda',1950);
insert into Vehicle (LicensePlate,Make,CarYear) values ('2134 FF','Toyota',1992);
```

```
-- Company has decided not to purchase any more car that were made before 2018. Add appropriate constraints to the Vehicle table to enforce this requirement.

alter table Vehicle add constraint checker_1 check (CarYear > 2018);
```

Comment: Please show us the structure of the `vehicle` table. Maybe another column can be used to identify newly added cars?

Comment: Do you want to check on the current table data or you want to check when inserting new data to the table?

Comment: i believe it should be to check the current data that is in the table.

Comment: If like that, you can't add `constraint` to the table. I assume you still have use for the data where the `CarYear < 2018`, correct? How about checking it in a query?

Comment: yes i still have use for it in other queries so i cant delete or alter the data , how would i check it in a query ? I'm still a bit of a beginner. couldn't i enforce it or would that not work?

Comment: In query you just add `WHERE CarYear > 2018` but if you need to show all cars and at the same time identify which cars are `CarYear > 2018` then you can add `CASE` in `SELECT` like `CASE WHEN CarYear > 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS car_year_chk` as another column.

Comment: So, you mean it's something you can work with? Or is there a problem with the result it returns? Maybe you can post your expected results.

Comment: it's something i can work with thank you very much for your assistance thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query if it's feasible for your operation:

```
SELECT LicensePlate, Make, CarYear,
         CASE WHEN CarYear > 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS car_year_chk
FROM Vehicle;
```

On your current sample data, you'll get this result:

| LicensePlate | Make | CarYear | car_year_chk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 AA | Toyota | 1970 | 0 |
| 1237 AB | Mazda | 1995 | 0 |
| 1876 FA | Nissan | 1999 | 0 |
| 1892 BG | Toyota | 2000 | 0 |
| 2134 FF | Toyota | 1992 | 0 |
| 3021 AA | Mazda | 1950 | 0 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9o1WFG9m)

Comment: would me checking it as a query enforce the rule -   not to purchase any more car that were made before 2018?

Comment: Where is this happening? On a web app? I guess if you really want to do something like that, just restrict the results/output with only cars made after 2018, directly using `WHERE CarYear > 2018`. If you still want to show them all and disabling the car selection through web app (front end), that's a different program/process and I suggest you post a new question.